# Lambda as a template variable

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

During some investigation related to "Variable template" I found out some strange code behaviour for me. Does standard say anything about this behaviour?

```
//Header.h
#pragma once

template<typename T>
auto myvar = []() -> T&{
    static T v;
    return v;
};

//Source.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Header.h"

void testFunction()
{
    std::cout << myvar<int>() << '\n';
}

//main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Header.h"

void testFunction();

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    myvar<int>() = 10;

    testFunction();

    std::cout << myvar<int>() << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
0
10
```

I expect:

```
10
10
```

Comment: You have two different instantiations of the template, one in each [*translation unit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)). Each instance of the function will have its own static local variable. This is fine and expected.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: I would say ODR violation, so no valid expectation.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're setting out to prove here but I can't say I like this code.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude aren't variable templates instantiations implicitly inline?

Comment: @Quentin Doesn't say [on cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variable_template), but it might be in the specification.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you have ODR violation:

In both translation units, you have (after substitution)

```
auto myvar<int> = []() -> int&{
    static int v;
    return v;
};
```

but lambda declares a different type for each TU,
so you have `lambda1` and `lambda2` for `myvar<int>`.

Each lambda has its own `static`, that is why you see that result in practice (but program is ill-formed anyway, NDR).

Comment: It looks like a truth. I don't see any other explanation. (But if I declare any other type for example "int" it works as I expect. Note: in the last Vandevoorde's book "C++ Templates: The Complete Guide" he says that each instance of "Template variable" in the different translation unit has inline behaviour and value is shared). It seems that such behaviour only related to lambdas. Tnx