# Are template variables allowed within multiple translation units and effectively merged?

Tags: c++, templates

See the following:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#One_Definition_Rule

http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#12

It states that multiple definitions of class templates, static data members of class templates, partial template specializations, etc are allowed and will act as one single definition. Great... but it does not mention variable templates anywhere?

If I have the following in multiple translation units:

```
template<typename T>
T my_data{};

inline void test() {
    my_data<int> = 1;
}
```

Will each translation unit will be given their own definition of `my_data` resulting in multiple symbols, or will they all be effectively merged into a single definition within the program where calling `test()` in one translation unit will modify the variable for another translation unit?

Where in the standard does it mention this behavior?

Comment: This looks like a more generic version of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52629501/lambda-as-a-template-variable)

Comment: Is there a specific version of C++ (like C++17?) you care about, or every version that supports variable templates?

Comment: C++14 specifically, but I am assuming it is the same explanation for any that supports variable templates. I am trying to figure out if what I am doing falls under NDR... but the program seems to behave correctly under Clang.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the c++14 standard [[basic.def]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/basic.def.odr#4):

> Every program shall contain exactly one definition of every non-inline function or variable that is odr-used in that program outside of a discarded statement; no diagnostic required.

So if `my_data<T>` is ord-used with the same template argument in multiple translation unit, you should have a odr-violation (without any diagnostic). `inline` variables appeared in c++17 to solve that problem and this is why `type_traits` *_v family of variable template are declared `inline`.

In practice, with Gcc and Clang (at least, I cannot check other compilers), you will not get any odr violation because template variables have "vague linkage" (as if they were declared inline).

You can check it with `nm`. If you run this command line `g++ -c test.cpp -std=c++14 && nm test.o | c++filt | grep my_data`, you should see that `my_data<int>` is a symbol of categorie `u` which is according to `nm` documentation :

> The symbol is a unique global symbol.  This is a GNU extension to the standard set of ELF symbol bindings.  For such a symbol the dynamic linker will make sure that in the entire process there is just one symbol with this name and type in use.

---

In [Core issue #1849](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_active.html#1849) one can read this obscure sentence:

> The description in 6.2 [basic.def.odr] paragraph 6 of when entities can be multiply-declared in a program does not, but should, discuss variable templates.

I would bet that if all compilers give to variable templates a vague linkage, a future revision of the standard may reflect that. But for now we should use the inline specifier as it is done in the stl.